# how to authenticate users without saving passwords in database

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, onlinebanking

I am developing a banking demo application. In my region users log-in to their bank website and do some transaction based on two fields that they have(You can assume two passwords- we call them cvv2 and Second-Password). These two passwords are only using for internet or mobile transactions.

I am sure that they do not save these passwords in database; because if they save these passwords in database, then the database administrator can use them and do fake transaction without real user permission.

By the way the question is that how the bank and its web site authenticate users and check that the entered fields(that two passwords) are right when they do not save these passwords in the data base.

Comment: Of course they are stored one way or another in a database. How would authentication take place. Banking like other parts of life is based on trust

Comment: According to PCIDSS the banking systems should not store the fields, some part of them or any combination of them in the database. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/

Comment: Encrypt them. But they are there and as an insider it can be broken

Comment: Anyway if a dba just execute a sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most banking systems today, do not rely on simple passwords, they have a two-factor authentication inplace. This could be for example an independend device to generate a code using your credit-card, or a least a TAN list.

When they store a password (usually done in combination with other security measures), then you can be sure that they store a *hash* of the password. A hash is one-way, you cannot get back the original password from it. Good hash algorithms for storing passwords are BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt, because they offer a cost factor. If you are interested to read more about the topic, you can have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) abour securely storing passwords.

Comment: if we store the hash the problem do not fix. because still we are checking the hash of the user entered password with the hash we have in the database. so db admin can create fake requests and send the hash so that checker function can not determine whether real user send it or not

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad - No he cannot. The checker function needs the original password and calculates a hash on its own, the hashes are compared then. Since it is nearly impossible to find a password resulting in the same hash, the admin cannot send a fake request.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this but found a way to not store the password in the database and still authenticate the user.

You can create a payload of username and password, something like "username + password" and then hash it using bcrypt or any other algorithms.

Store this hash in the database with the username field.
In this way, the password won't be stored anywhere.

Next time you want to authenticate you can take the username and password and generate the hash from it and match which is present in the database. Only the correct password will result in same hash.

Please correct me if I am wrong and there is an flaw in this.

Comment: Well, there are a few flaws in your logic: 1. You are doing basically the same thing as storing a pasword in the database, you just add a username to it. 2. You are storing password and username in the same column, which is a bad practice, even if the field is hashed. 3. Your solution makes it impossible to execute database quries based on the username, because you know... there is no actual username stored anywhere.

Comment: 1. true
2. Can you please help me understand why this is not good practice, its kind of a new practice. What is the issue in this?
3. username would stored in a col. The table will look like: | username | hashed_username+password |